# Wordpress on docker compose doesn't load css

Tags: wordpress, docker

I'm new to docker and databases but my first project on local host doesn't load as expected. The side appears but the content is scattered. Here is the .yml file

```
version: "3.9"
    
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you run

```
$ docker-compose up
```

Docker create a new network to which all the containers in your compose file will be connected to.

In the first run of this compose file, you do the installation of Wordpress,
and Wordpress insert the IP address of your web site in the database.

The problem occur when you stop this compose file with:

```
$ docker-compose down
```

the network created with "docker-compose up" is removed
and when you run the compose file again, docker will create a new network with different IP addresses, so links become broken because your webpages still point to the old IP address.

A solution can be to create a network outside compose file with:

```
$ docker network create my_network
```

and empty the volume "dbdata" and the folder "./www" (and lose all your data) then update your compose file with:

```
version: "3.9"
    
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress

volumes:
  db_data: {}
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my_network
```

I think there is solution to this problem without losing your data, for more information you can read this [article](https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/).